# Dynamic forms with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflow

I'm searching for a way to display dynamic forms with Spring Boot, Spring MVC and Thymleaf. What I want is to change the form based on previous inputs. Eg:

- If the User selects TypA in Input1 show Input 2, 3 and 4.
- If the User selects TypB in Input1 show Input 3, 4 and 5.

I have evaluated some methods to achieve this.

1. **JavaScript:** Show and hide the inputs with JS. This gets really messy and adds important logic into the view. Not what I really like to do.
2. **AJAX and Fragments:** Replace parts of the webpage with ajax that requests the forms as Thymeleaf fragments from the backend. This keeps the loginc in the backend but is not very flexible. I have to create all possible combinations of forms to always include the right one.
3. **Spring Web Flow:** Define the form as a Web Flow that decides which parts to show next. Sounds good but seems a little bit overkill to me. Also it has is steep learning curve and there is not much documentation/tutorials on Spring Web Flow with Thymeleaf.

What is the way to go? Are there better ways / libraries / framworks to achieve this?

As a bonus client side input validation would be nice but is not necessary.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know how complex is your business logic, but I would go for the 1 option, or depends on what you need, the 2

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The logic is not very complex, yet. However I don't know if it stays this simple or will become more complex. Thats way I was looking for the best way to keep it dynamic.